# Is it possible to hide the contents of a js.erb file in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Just realized that when I go to `foo/:id/method.js` my code is being exposed. Is there a way to hide this or redirect "snoopers"?

---

I've seen it done before. When I figure out what site it was, I'll post it here

---

See my answer below

Comment: There is no way to do this. I don't need to navigate to that URL the browser shows the JS from the request on your page so hiding it at the URL itself would offer you no protection. Just open your JS Console and look the source for this site.

Comment: I assume that you have dynamic content in your `.js.erb` right otherwise why would you have it serve it from your controller at all? Either way I think the best you could do is check whether your user is in a state where he/she can access it or not… But if what you are looking for is completely hide it, as the answer below and comment above suggest, **you can't**.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to mitigate "snoopers", you could minify your Javascript which would obfuscate your code by making it unreadable, but **there is no way to completely hide it.** It's best just to write safe code, and not be so uptight about people looking at your Javascript, because if they want to see it, they will. Not sure what site you're talking about, but I guarantee you I can access the Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my little work around for now 
Since I'm using a js.erb with Rails. You basically throw in a couple of if statements. I'm working on it now & will test it out